# pandas: compare two columns in df, return combined value ranges across rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a large df that looks like:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'start': [1, 1, 2, 8, 2000],
                     'end': [5, 3, 6, 9, 3000]})

start   end
0   1   5
1   1   3
2   2   6
3   8   9
4   2000    3000
```

I want to compare all rows of `test` and get the combined value ranges:

desired output:

```
start   end
0   1   6
1   8   9
2   2000    3000
```

I know I can compare within a row, e.g.

```
test['start'] < test['end]
```

I'm just not sure of the best/fastest way to compare and combine over millions of rows.

Comment: This is a merge interval problem. I believe you need a custom function to deal with this.